# save data based on one column and named by other column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a dataset in this format:

```
    A                 B             LABEL   NEW
-0.027651         -0.068485            5      1  
-0.039997         -0.071371            5      1  
-0.032667         -0.078227            5      1  
-0.021502         -0.083501            5      1  
-0.018613         -0.082452            5      1  
 0.134058         -0.145095            7      2  
-0.164757          0.029179            4      3  
-0.124876          0.022431            4      3  
-0.076959         -0.021404            4      3
-0.221781          0.163064            8      4  
 0.137542         -0.250567            5      5  
 0.048786         -0.153115            5      5  
-0.001230         -0.095431            5      5
```

I want to split the dataframe by new column value 1:

```
    A                 B             LABEL      NEW
-0.027651         -0.068485            5     1  
-0.039997         -0.071371            5     1  
-0.032667         -0.078227            5     1  
-0.021502         -0.083501            5     1  
-0.018613         -0.082452            5     1
```

and save according to the name of that label:
like (NEW-LABEL)--> "1-5.csv"

I have 7000 rows, I need to do it dynamically SPLIT and Save,

Answer (score 3):

Use `groupby` on `NEW` to split

```
In [11]: for n, g in df.groupby('NEW'):
    ...:     g.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(n))
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, NOW the files are saved in 1.csv,2.csv,3.csv..... where 1 2 3 comes from groupby column NEW, it's correct but I also need to put which label its belong to, so I can write it on when saving the files, like "NEW-LABEL.csv" i.e 1-5.csv etc

Answer (score 1):

Now I know what you mean

```
for x,df1 in df.groupby('NEW'):
    df1.to_csv("%s.csv" % x)
```

Update

```
for x,df1 in df.groupby('NEW'):
    df1.to_csv("%s-%s.csv" % (x,df1.LABEL[0]))
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, NOW the files are saved in 1.csv,2.csv,3.csv..... where 1 2 3 comes from groupby column NEW, it's correct but I also need to put which label its belong to, so I can write it on when saving the files, like "NEW-LABEL.csv" i.e 1-5.csv etc

Comment: File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 83, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 811, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 817, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item